# Stack overflow creating an archive using libzip

Tags: c++, zip, stack-overflow

To get started with [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html), I tried to create an archive and add a file to it. This is my code.

```
string archive  = "path/to/archive.zip";
string file     = "message";
char *data      = "Hello World!";

int error = 0;
zip *archive = zip_open(path.c_str(), ZIP_CREATE, &error);
if(error)
{
    cout << "could not open or create archive" << endl;
    return false;
}

zip_source *source = zip_source_buffer(archive, data, sizeof(data), 0);
if(source == NULL)
{
    cout << "failed to create source buffer. " << zip_strerror(archive) << endl;
    return false;
}

int index = (int)zip_file_add(archive, file.c_str(), source, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
if(index < 0)
{
    cout << "failed to add file to archive. " << zip_strerror(archive) << endl;
    return false;
}

zip_source_free(source);
zip_close(archive);

return true;
```

This code throws a runtime error at the `zip_close()` call.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00EDDD16 in Application.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002C2FFC).

Update: I removed the `zip_source_free()` call since I was told that this is already done by `zip_file_add()`. Moreover, I check `archive` to not hold `NULL`. These changes raised another error at `zip_close()`.

> Unhandled exception at 0x0065BC57 in Application.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The declaration of `data` won't even compile in C++11, as modifying string literals is pointless.

Comment: @chris `data` is just for testing. I took it from the [documentation](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_file_add.html#x4558414d504c4553). It compiles without warnings in Visual Studio 11.

Comment: There is also an extra closing parenthesis in `zip_open` before `.c_str()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `zip_source_free()` since `source` has already been used in `zip_file_add()` and freed there.

Also, you should check the *return value* of `zip_open()` instead of the value of `errorp`. Nothing in the documentation indicates that error codes are different than 0. However, the return value *will* be `NULL` if the zip file cannot be opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <zip.h>
    
// apt-get install libzip-dev
// gcc source.c -lzip
    
    int main(){
       const char * path  = "archive.zip";
       const char * file     = "message";
       const char * data      = "Hello World!";
    
       int error = 0;
       struct zip *archive = zip_open(path, ZIP_CREATE, &error);
       if(error){
          printf("could not open or create archive\n");
          return -1;
       }
       struct zip_source *source = zip_source_buffer(archive, data, strlen(data), 0);
       if(source == NULL){
          printf("failed to create source buffer. %s\n",zip_strerror(archive));
          return -1;
       }
    
       int index = (int)zip_file_add(archive, file, source, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
       if(index < 0){
          printf("failed to add file to archive: %s\n",zip_strerror(archive));
          return -1;
       }
    
       //zip_source_free(source);
       zip_close(archive);
    
       return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).